# Is it possible to change a field automatically through a package when the user's password is modified?

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm developing a laravel-php package where i need to update a field "password_changed_at" when the user changes his password.
I need to make this update happen through a package.
Is there ways to do this?

Comment: You could register an updated or updating hook to your user model over a package service provider. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Simply by creating an observer in the package that updates the field when the user is updated and calling it in the AppServiceProvider's project.